# Installing python 3.5 via apt-get

Tags: python

I am attempting to install python 3.5 via apt-get
I did the following

```
> sudo apt-get install python3.5
...
Unable to locate package python3.5
```

And the response says that it cant find python3.5.
I tried doing `apt-get update` but that did not help as well

Any suggestions ? These are my details

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
```

More update:

```
apt-cache policy python3 python
python3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.2.3-6
  Version table:
     3.2.3-6 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main armhf Packages
python:
  Installed: 2.7.3-4+deb7u1
  Candidate: 2.7.3-4+deb7u1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: This is off topic for SO as it is not programming related. Also, if you post questions like these (no matter where) you should at least include which distro and version you're using.

Comment: I dont think this is off topic - setting up an environment is not considered off topic. Also I included the details of my distro

Comment: Search the Debian package database: https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [Don Kirkby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393054/installing-python-3-5-via-apt-get#comment93543600_38393177) who highlight that there is a new recommended PPA.
The updated one is `ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`, so the complete command is the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

---

---

If you are using Ubuntu, you can install it adding a PPA; so you can proceed in this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.5
```

If this procedure doesn't work, is possible that your Ubuntu version not supported it. So i think that you can install in this way:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.0/Python-3.5.0.tgz
tar xzvf Python-3.5.0.tgz
cd Python-3.5.0
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found

Comment: doing a sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties

Comment: look at this post please: http://askubuntu.com/questions/493460/how-to-install-add-apt-repository-using-the-terminal

Comment: Nope that didnt work either - I managed to install sudo add-apt-repository but then it still cant find python 3.5

Comment: run "apt-cache policy" and check if you can find new repository

Comment: yes i can find new repos.

Comment: Ok, so run "update" and after if you try to install python3.5 what kind of error do you have?

Comment: unfortunately that gives the same result

Comment: Although the first method is right under Ubuntu, on Debian it is a bad idea to use PPA repositories ([as indicated here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=125904)). Under Debian, the right way is to manually install as indicated in the second method. I would just modify the `./configure` command and use `./configure --prefix /usr/local` instead. But this may depend on your system's configuration. Very good answer indeed

Comment: Recommended PPA has changed. Now you should use `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`.

Comment: Note: Python2.7 (both), Python 3.5 (xenial), Python 3.6 (bionic) are not provided by deadsnakes as upstream ubuntu provides those packages.

Answer (score -5):

Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3.2
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libssl1.0.0 tk8.5-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
```

Download Python 3.3.0:

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.0/Python-3.3.0.tgz
```

Extract:

```
tar xvfz Python-3.3.0.tgz
Configure and Install:
cd Python-3.3.0
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3
make  
sudo make install
```

Test if it worked:

```
/opt/python3.3/bin/python3
```

Comment: i am looking for python 3.5 python 3.2 is available through apt-get

Comment: Just change 3.3 to 3.5 and see , I think it will work !

Answer (score -6):

try with a simple search first:

> apt-cache search python | grep 3.5

Comment: It does not return anything