# accidently delete python libraries

Tags: python, unix

I accidently deleted all python2.7 python3 python 3.5 and python3.6 in usr/local/lib and in usr/lib i'm really new to the UNIX environment so I have no idea what I just did but I can't use python anymore ... any help?

Comment: Install fresh if you have not messed up the OS already. But you probably do. Because python 2.7 and python3.5 is heavily integrated with the OS.  

here is a url to install python3.5: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38393177/6029175 and install python2.7: https://askubuntu.com/a/981279

[ IN FUTURE: DONT REMOVE BUILT IN PYTHON LIBRARIES. IT WILL SCREW UP YOUR SYSTEM ]

Comment: Being new to UNIX can do that sometimes :) Don't be afraid to reinstall the entire system if necessary, that's how you learn what not to do in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward approach might be to remove and reinstall python.

For example reinstalling `python3`

```
sudo apt-get remove python3
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Adapted from the following SO answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044572/1844376

Another approach could be:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall python`

Adapted from: https://askubuntu.com/a/448927/665609