# pip ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.6.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to install tensorflow 1.6.0 to use a python project, I'm on ubuntu 20

The problem is that I couldn't find the tensorflow 1.6.0 as its needed by the project and it doesnt work on tensorflow +2, this is the error I'm getting :

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.6.0 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.6.0
```

my pip version is 20.0.2 and i have a python 3.8.2 64bit, what is causing this problem? why pip cannot find tensorflow versions below 2?

the only close solution i found was this :

[Tensorflow r1.0 : could not a find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317075/tensorflow-r1-0-could-not-a-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tens)

but the links in the tensorflow webpage for linux are all for tensorflow +2 and when i replace the version with 1.6.0 it doesnt work anymore :

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [tensorflow.org](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip), "Python 3.8 support requires TensorFlow 2.2 or later."

Comment: So what is the easiest solution for me to  use tensorflow 1.6 on Ubuntu 20 and run this project?

Comment: You can run a previous version of python. You could run a a python version less than 3.8 by using pyenv https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv. Pyenv allows you to install + manage previous python versions.

Comment: i also found another solution here which enables installing any python versions alongside my own by adding deadsnakes PPA, is there any benefit of using this instead of pyenv? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393054/installing-python-3-5-via-apt-get

Comment: I am familiar with pyenv - not so much with dead snakes PPA. There are a handful of options, and python version management could be a separate SO question.

Comment: If you found this post to be helpful, please consider accepting the answer.